# Is there an algorithm to get a set of $n$ distinct vectors which generates the given $n$ vectors, whose degree follows the irreducible factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, smith-normal-form

For example, for $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$, its smith normal form is $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&4\end{pmatrix}$.
So I can calculate the smith normal form, or the irreducible factorization of given $n$ vectors.
However, I couldn't find which vectors have order of such factorization, 4 in this example.
Of course, this example is easy enough and I can easily give a vector $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}$ which 4 is the smallest natural number which $n\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}\in \{v\in\mathbb{R}^2|v=k_1\begin{pmatrix}2&1\end{pmatrix}+k_2\begin{pmatrix}0&2\end{pmatrix},k_1,k_2\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. How do I find such vectors in general, assuming all $n$ vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and are linearly independent?

Comment: The Smith Normal Form algorithm also computes the transforming matrices $P$, $Q$, such that $PAQ = S$, with $S$ in Smith Normal Form, and either $P$ or $Q$ (can't remember which, and it depends on whether you are using right or left actions) gives the new basis in terms of the old, which is what you are looking for.

Comment: @DerekHolt If you're right, then I guess that $Q$ should contain those vectors. The problem is, I am not so sure about it. But thanks for your help, maybe I can figure it out now.